# Simulating a bigendian environment or load a bigendian simulator for testing purpose

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, ios-simulator, xctest

I have a binary file which needs to be decoded. This file stores bytes in a bigendian fashion. I have created a cocoatouch framework and I use this binary file as a resource. When loaded I am able to decode it in a little endian environment. I have written some unit tests and it passes the decoding.

Now I have also written some tests where this bigendian binary file can be read on a bigendian machine and assert the tests. Unfortunately I don't have a bigendian machine to perform this test.

So can I simulate this?

My abstract gist of tests is as below:

Bigendian binary file ----loaded on littleendian machine---> Decoding success

Bigendian binary file ----load on bigendian machine -----> Decoding success or failure is not testable due to simulation restrictions.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the encoding/decoding code?

Comment: @Cristik the decoding part is fairly simple. I use an instance of FileHandle to access say n bytes at a time using UnsafePointers in Swift. Now for this n bytes I determine various integer types using UInt(bigEndian:) initializers as I know my file contains bigendian storage pattern.

Comment: OK, then assuming `UInt(bigEndian:)` correctly works on both little and big endian, then you only need to test your other code, which should be endianess-agnostic.

Comment: @Cristik Thanks for your comment. To clarify if I missed anything here is a link to gist: https://gist.github.com/raditz2488/c1d84be7bb851d454d5c16f404ebffb7

I am sure the code I wrote to pass the test is endian agnostic. Its the test that I am worried about. I am having a go at TDD and this means all cases should be covered. If I see them passing even once on a bigendian environment, it would be comforting.

Comment: Looking at the code, there is only one scenario to test: big endian decoding. So, you only need one test, a test that should not care if it's run on a big/little endian environment. The endianness you're worrying about is part of the system SDK, and that one I'm sure has lots of tests, so you should be covered.